# Yahoo fetching data MATLAB

Tags: matlab, yahoo

I have the list of the securities' tickers. I would like to download close prices and store them into the variable. I wrote this script:

```
function y=fetchDataFromYahoo()
    ticker={'ABFS','TCB','NE','FGP'};%,'IMO','CAJ','CAG','GMCR','HSH','HAIN','SIM'};
    c=yahoo;
    for i=1:4
        Price.(ticker{i})=fetch(c,ticker(i),'Adj Close','Jan 1 00','Apr 19 13','d');
        temp=Price.(ticker{i});
        ClosePrice(:,i)=temp(:,2);
    end
    y=ClosePrice;
end
```

It works when I have three securities in the array, but it throws the error when there are more than 3 securities in the array. The error message is the following:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

    Error in fetchDataFromYahoo (line 7)
            ClosePrice(:,i)=temp(:,2);
```

Would you be so kind to help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming that all series will be same length. Just keep it in a structure:

```
fetchDataFromYahoo({'ABFS','TCB','NE','FGP'})
```

where I modified your function to:

```
function Price = fetchDataFromYahoo(ticker)
    c = yahoo;
    for i = 1:numel(ticker)
        Price.(ticker{i}) = fetch(c,ticker(i),'Adj Close','Jan 1 00','Apr 19 13','d');
    end
end
```

The result of the call (first line of code):

```
ans = 
    ABFS: [3337x2 double]
     TCB: [3337x2 double]
      NE: [3337x2 double]
     FGP: [3343x2 double]
```

**EDIT** to address comments

To accomodate financial time series with different lengths in a matrix, you need to fill with NaNs where data for specific days is missing. You will need [`rude()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436-rude-a-pedestrian-run-length-decoder-encoder) and my [`Pivot()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26119-pivotunpivot):

```
% Use the modified function that returns a structure
D   = fetchDataFromYahoo({'ABFS','TCB','NE','FGP'});

% Convert to cell
C   = struct2cell(D);

% Count how many rows each cell
len = cellfun('size',C,1);

% Expand id to match each series length
Out = Pivot([rude(len,1:numel(C))', cat(1,C{:})]);
```

You can see in `Out` that ABFS, TCB and NE are missing the day corresponding to row 37 (you can also double check this in D, date 730539 missing).

Comment: Thank you for your answering! However, I would like to receive a matrix with the all prices (not struct) because then I want to apply price2ret function of the matlab.

Comment: This is a totally different question, because you need to align the dates filling the empty spots in FGP with NANs.

Comment: Would you be so kind to elaborate more on your suggestion? What does it mean: FGP?